# MS SQL database changes are not writing back to Umbraco CMS backend

Tags: database, synchronization, umbraco

I’m using Umbraco v4.11.10 CMS and have made bulk changes to member expiry dates via scripts in the MS SQL-server database. However, when I go back to the Umbraco backend, the changes aren’t being shown. The changes are being made to the “cms.ContentXml” tables in MS SQL.

Is there any way to force or sync the Umbraco CMS backend to show the values in the database? I understand Umbraco writes the data to XML so I deleted the umbraco.config file but that doesn’t help.

Comment: It's highly likely that what you are seeing is the Internal Members Index used by Umbraco not being updated after you've updated the tables.  That being said, you are using Umbraco 4.11, and this might be a question better handled on the Umbraco Forums.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Robert

Comment: Hi Robert, I just noticed that you're making changes to the ContentXml table - sorry, I assumed you were editing the member record data.  See my answer below.  My initial comment in this case doesn't apply.

Answer (score 0):

The ContentXml table is a kind of half-way house for Umbraco's content and shouldn't be edited directly, as it gets overwritten as soon as you make any change to the object in question and then save it.

The underlying data for Umbraco content (including media, content, and members) is actually stored in several other tables using a very flexible object graph structure and not easily editable via straightforward sql scripts.

Under the hood, it goes something like this:

1. User Edits an item (Member, Content, Media, etc.) and saves it.
2. [If it's a Content item] Umbraco creates a new version by copying the current version.
3. For each property of the item, Umbraco creates a new record in the cmsPropertyData table according to the datatypes storage type (int, date, nvarchar, ntext) and linked to the item's record via the propertyId and itemId.
4. Once the data has been saved, an XML representation of the object is generated and deposited into the cmsContentXml table, overwriting any previous versions for that item.
5. If it is a Content item, and the item is published, Umbraco will then write that same XML representation to the Umbraco.config cache file.

This is a fairly simplistic representation; but should suffice to give you an idea of the complexity involved in saving and modifying the data.

I propose that you take advantage of Umbraco's extensive API to do bulk changes to records by writing a plugin - there may also be plugins available that do something similar, and you may be able to leverage those, or obtain the code of some of them, as they are quite commonly open source; and base your code off that.